# Download Ubuntu as Zip? iso download blocked

Tags: downloads

I sit behind the most poorly set up network ever. However, it blocks certain file extensions like .iso, .exe or .msi (thankfully I don't need the last 2 mentioned ones).
My problem is, that the ubuntu downloads are no longer .zip and that prevents me from upgrading to 13.10. I don't trust any others pages so I think it might be a good idea to offer both, .iso AND .zip for all versions on ubuntu.com, or is it already?

Thanks for listening.

Comment: Can you download a torrent?

Comment: Unfortunately not, only port 80, 433 and some useless MS ports are open, but so far I never made it behind that :/

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to asist you. The only option I think you have is to download it off another network or contact the owner of the network.

Comment: Cheers dude, I just asked a friend to send it to me through IM.. is it legal to publish the .zip on my own FTP so people don't run into the same problem as I do? There exist VERY few threads about my problem but I'd love to help them as don't wanna be like MS only going for the big users.

Comment: @user2161301 Yes, you can offer Ubuntu for download on your site. (If you actually modify the contents of the image, *then* you should take extra care to heed the requirements of applicable licenses.) I'm not a lawyer and I don't officially represent the project in saying that, but if you need--and cannot find--more authoritative information about that, please do feel free to post a new question about it. By the way, getting it from a friend via IM (or otherwise) is a reusable solution that may help others, so you may want to post an answer including it (when the system allows you to).

Comment: Another reason this is desirable is that my USB drives have stuff on them, I don't want to erase them when unpacking the ISO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there were a *totally* official Ubuntu mirror that used [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure), that might be your best bet: unless you have configured your computer to recognize the proxy you're required to use as its own certificate authority (which would be [insecure unless you totally trust the proxy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40892/what-are-the-risks-associated-with-ssl-interception-in-an-organization) and [controversial](https://www.grc.com/fingerprints.htm) [anyway](http://www.zdnet.com/nokia-hijacks-mobile-browser-traffic-decrypts-https-data-7000009655/)), the software that restricts what you may download cannot distinguish filenames by extension, through HTTPS.

Unfortunately, the [current official mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors) for Ubuntu ISOs are http, ftp, and rsync only.

**Fortunately**, HTTP mirrors occasionally support HTTPS as well. By going through the list, you'll often find a small number that do. In particular, **you can download Ubuntu ISO images from https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu-releases/.**

(The HTTP version of that site actually isn't listed--I got it by removing the "us" subdomain prefix from http://mirrors.us.kernel.org/ubuntu-releases/. The HTTPS version of that site should work too but you'll get scary warnings in your browser because its security certificate is for the unprefixed domain instead.)

Note that, once Ubuntu is installed, you may have some trouble *updating* it and installing software in it, depending on what extensions you can download via HTTP. In particular, you must be able to download `.deb` files. Hopefully the block is limited to just a few extensions rather than blocking everything *but* just a few extensions.

You can also make Ubuntu use HTTPS download mirrors to update and install software, same as with HTTP. I don't know of any HTTPS sites mirroring Ubuntu's official software sources--those mirrors aren't, in general, all the same as the mirrors for ISO images--but if you need that, you could post a new question about it. (In your question you should explain *why* you need it, as otherwise it will likely be answered with an explanation of how APT operates securely even though archives are downloaded via HTTP.)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a HTTPS link but I couldn't find one. But I found something interesting, that you can use rsync to download ubuntu and according to wikipedia it uses port TCP 873 (MAC and Linux OS'ses most of the times rsync come preloaded, but for Windows you may need to download rsync). Anyway, here's the mirror list to download ubuntu https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors

Good Luck

Comment: [I'd found](http://askubuntu.com/a/439793/22949) one -- https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu-releases/ -- does that not work for you? Also ...I think that if you can download through rsync, you can likely download torrents as well. (You may not be able to receive incoming connections while torrenting, but for big, healthy torrents like those for ISO images of supported Ubuntu releases, it should still download at a pretty good speed.)

Comment: That's true. If he can't download ubuntu through the HTTPS link then it could be related to the local computer's antivirus or malware protection.

Answer (score -1):

Just save the "ubuntu.iso" as "ubuntu.zip" and then re-change the extension back after you've downloaded the file.

Comment: very good idea, but that throws 
"ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.zip Unknown server error. Please try again, or contact the server administrator." 
in chrome

Comment: @mango What filename one *saves* a file *as* doesn't change the filename that is requested from the server. (Only the filename requested from the server goes through the proxy so only it can be used as a basis for selectively blocking downloads.)

Comment: @Eliah Kagan I learned something new today :)

Comment: Actually I think that MIGHT work depending on the proxy setup. Remember that we used to be able to do the ?JPG airport hack..

Comment: @user2161301 *That* is a good idea. It's different from what this answer suggests, though. While simply changing what filename you put into the "Save as" (or equivalent) dialog box doesn't change what is requested from the server, adding `?` followed by an allowed extension *does* change what filename is requested from the server (though not necessarily the filename it's saved as locally). You may want to add this as a new answer yourself (especially if it works for you).